# Visual Studio 2017 RC Install Error "The specified account already exists."

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I try to install Visual Studio 2017 RC I got this error :

```
[1764:001d][2016-11-20T10:14:21] Package 'Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi,version=1.0.1967,chip=x64' failed to repair. MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi,version=1.0.1967,chip=x64\ancm_iis_express_x64_en.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  ALLUSERS="1"  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  REINSTALL=ALL  REINSTALLMODE="cmuse" IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL , Return code: 1316, Details: The specified account already exists.
```

Installation process gives me (Failed to setup) on 94% progress with above log error
Can anyone help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happened to me as well and the reason is that Visual Studio 2017 setup cannot uninstall the existing IIS Express package. Try this:

1. Quit the VS 2017 installer setup and go to this location "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi,version=1.0.1967,chip=x64"

   [image]

   2. There must be an .msi file with name "ancm_iis_express_x64_en.msi".
      Run that msi and remove the component (there must be a remove option).
   3. Once done restart the VS 2017 setup again and this time you get past issue with this component. If you encounter similar error, please read the error message, track the package from Packages folder and uninstall that.

Please note that uninstalling any package wont affect an existing package for VS 2015/2013.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, visual studio gives me the option to launch after fails, so I launched but I will try your answer to avoid caches..

Comment: This also fixes if you try to repair visual studio.

Comment: @BartCalixto I'm getting the same error when trying to *repair* Visual Studio!

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. I hope the final version of VS 2017 will have less flaws like these.

Comment: Worth noting that you should be OK to ignore the warning that says that 2 programs will fail to work if you uninstall this package