# Can't get past Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.msi in VS2017 RC Update

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I previously successfully installed Visual Studio 2017 RC Enterprise on Windows 10 Home.  I saw in the Notifications area an update to a later version of the RC, and so I clicked on that notification to install it.

The installation got as far as the attempting to install the Android Emulators, but failed and the log said it needed Win10 Pro.

So I removed the emulator from the install options, but the install didn't complete and this time the log said:

```
[27ac:0038][2017-01-31T10:08:47] Download requested: https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/7/A/87AEAAB0-D624-400E-899E-61FAFAE42BA5/Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.Msi.msi
[27ac:003a][2017-01-31T10:08:47] Attempting download 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/7/A/87AEAAB0-D624-400E-899E-61FAFAE42BA5/Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.Msi.msi' using engine 'WebClient'
[27ac:0026][2017-01-31T10:08:48] Completed: Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi
[27ac:0026][2017-01-31T10:08:48] Error: Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.26109.1' failed to install. MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.26109.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  VS7.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise" , Return code: 1316, Details: The specified account already exists.
```

I tried to follow the instructions from [Visual Studio 2017 RC Install Error "The specified account already exists."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701935/visual-studio-2017-rc-install-error-the-specified-account-already-exists) however its says `the action is only valid for installed products`

Yesterday I did notice MinShell in the Programmes Uninstall list and tried removing it from there.

However it makes no difference and every time I try and run the installer I get the same error.  I have tried making sure that no VS2017 related items are installed in Programs and Features, and deleting directories manually from Program files etc

Starting to get really annoyed as I had a completely working compiler and IDE and I've already been totally unable to upgrade Win10 to the Anniversary Update due to the 0x8007002C – 0x400D error during Migrate-Data operation.  I tried the fix of resetting the Storage app to make all defaults C:, and then the Documents link, but that didn't fix it, although I see I've missed Downloads, Pictures and Video, so will try again tonight but I still don't see it working, although I think the failure moved from 79% to 83%

Answer (score 2):

@Peter Nimmo I had the same issue. Solve it by:

Go to C:\Program Data\Microsoft, go to Properties then click the Security tab and add System, then give full permission. The reason why it couldn't install is because it can't access the folder required.

Hope it works for you. If it doesn't, you could try the following additional steps:

Go to C:\ then at the search box type %temp% then delete everything in it.

Run this script in Powershell Admin mode: https://gist.github.com/heaths/77fbe0b44496960fab25c2eb0b9e8475.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be caused by setting a separate cache folder when installing. The steps below should fix it.

1. delete the `visualstudio` folder in your Registry editor `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`(under Microsoft?)
2. run `InstallCleanup.exe---> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout`
3. delete contents in your temp folder `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Temp`(skip items that cannot be deleted)

Answer (score 1):

run InstallCleanup.exe
inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout`
then restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

Go to %ProgramData%\Microsoft and rename VisualStudio folder (e.g. to VisualStudio_old)
Try again with fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Please temporarily disable 3rd party anti-virus software and try the following steps to check if it works for you:

1. Type “Administrative Tools” in search box
2. Open “Local Security Policy”
3. Navigate to “Software Restriction Policies” (If it displays “No Software Restrictions Defined”, please right-click on the “Software Restriction Policies” node and select “New Software Restriction Policies”)
4. Double-click on “Enforcement”
5. Select “All users except Local Administrators” and click on OK
6. Restart your computer and run the Visual Studio Installer as administrator to repair the installation

Please Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/147767/visual-studio-2019-can39t-install-microsoftvisuals.html

Answer (score -3):

similar error for me sort of, it starts installing then gets stuck on shell(minimum) and shell interops and the shell(minimum) resources and interop resources..then i get a fatal error, tells me that Visual Studio Devenv resource fails.. no matter what i try i cannot install on my windows 10 1607 anniversary update 3 64-bit with all updates to this minute. I read microsoft is aware and its become a huge problem, programming error. Anyone figures out how to install let me know please.

EDIT: so its a huge pain to get visual studio 2015 to install, i kept reinstalling it and everytime the error window came up i read the log, then i manually searched and installed components listed, and also had to manually create folders almost each time following the path listed in the log file. after 12 hours and alot of searching and installing i now have a fully functional visual studio 2015 pro edition back on my computer..i wanted 2017 but thats even worse to install..lol..

Comment: that is not exactly an answer.